# Update ComboBox when parent updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to bind a ComboBox that shows the client state in a client view form. I have a **context class** called *ClientUI* which has a property *CurrentClient* like this:

```
private Client _CurrentClient= null;
public Client CurrentClient
{
    get
    {
        return _CurrentClient;
    }
    set
    {
        _CurrentClient= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentClient");
    }
}
```

In my xaml form I have every property from *CurrentClient* like name, adress, etc. binded to textboxes. 
So when I do:

```
CurrentClient = SomeClient;
```

It automatically updates all fields in my form to show the new client.
Now I'm trying to bind a ComboBox with the client **Status** in my *ClientUI* I have a list of *Status* and my *CurrentClient* has a *Status* property.
*Status* is also a class with a property **Name** type string.

Here is my ComboBox binding:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentClient.Status, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientStatusList}" SelectedValuePath="Name"  />
```

And it works, when I change the ComboBox It changes the proprty in *CurrentClient* and when I force *CurrentClient.Status* like this...

```
CurrentClient.Status = ClientStatusList[0]
```

...the Combobox shows the value.
The issue is when I do

```
CurrentClient = SomeClient;
```

It updates every textBox but not the comboBox.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Does `SomeClient.Status` have value? Also, what's the result when you tried `CurrentClient.Status = SomeClient.Status` instead of `CurrentClient.Status = ClientStatusList[0]` ?

Comment: Thank you! `SomeClient.Status` has a value, but when i do `CurrentClient.Status = SomeClient.Status` nothing happens: `SomeClient.Status` is set to the new status but the comboBox does not update.

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding ClientStatusList}"` means there is a property called `ClientStatusList` in `Client` class. Check `ClientStatusList` has some value.

Answer (score 0):

Your "CurrentClient" property has property changed notification but does your "Status" property in your Client class have property changed notification? If not try adding the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to the Client class and then add property changed notification to your Status property.

Just because you have property changed notification on a property does not mean that sub-properties also do. For this reason binding to dotted-off properties can be temperamental.

If you do not have the option to edit your Client class then you could try creating another "status" property in your clientUI class that does have property-changed notification and then set that in your "CurrentClient" setter. You should be able to bind to this new property more reliably

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `Client` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `Status` property triggers `OnPropertyChanged`

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't any help